# How to avoid table join when passing linked table id value in JPA Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When using criteria below I want the SQL query with simple  where clause as employee.department_id = :departmentId but it generates inner join with employee and department table.

```
Criteria<Employee> criteria = Criteria.forClass(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("department.id", departmentId));
```

Are there anyway to force JPA criteria API to generate simplified SQL for the above scenario?

Comment: If departments are being loaded eagerly you can't unless you make them lazy.

Comment: I am using default lazy loading for department table join.